# Poset and lattice

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Define and verify on the set of positive divisors of 70 a poset,a lattice with its types,and a Boolean algebra.
I have tried to do this question but I don't know the correct method

Comment: How far did you get? The problem you describe has several parts. Were you able to describe the poset?

Comment: I tried it by making a hasse diagram

Comment: I suggest you add more details to the post about what you have tried and what results you have got so far.